# MySQL PDO general error 2014 when calling multiple stored procedures

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

I get the following error when calling a 2nd stored procedure using PHP PDO:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.

Normally this error occurs when you haven't used `fetchAll()` to get all the data back from MySQL before requesting more data. However in this case I am using fetchAll on all stored procedure calls.

Two workarounds are possible. Either use `$stmt->closeCursor()` after each stored procedure call or replace the stored procedures with SELECT queries instead.

Is there something about stored procedures that leaves data 'unfetched'?

Comment: Please post the stored procedure definitions. Do you SELECT _multiple_ result sets in one of them, but only `fetchAll()` from one result set without using [`nextRowset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php) for example?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I used a PDO fetchAll, [nextRowset();](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php)  then closeCursor(); this solved my problem.

Comment: Could you please write a more detailed answer with explanation insead of just typing a one code liner.

Comment: Sorry, this was actually my first post.. More info can be found at [nextRowset()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php). I had the same issue, I used a PDO fetchAll, nextRowset() thnen closeCursor()  , this solved my problem.

Comment: Please edit your answer instead of explaining in comment section